# Using scala.BigDecimal with Joda-Money

Tags: scala, joda-money

I am trying to use a scala BigDecimal with Joda-Money. Passing the scala BigDecimal to `Money.of()` does not work because it is expecting a Java BigDecimal.

```
[error] C:\test.scala:82: overloaded method value of with alternatives:
[error]   (x$1: org.joda.money.BigMoneyProvider,x$2: java.math.RoundingMode)org.joda.money.Money <and>
[error]   (x$1: org.joda.money.CurrencyUnit,x$2: Double)org.joda.money.Money <and>
[error]   (x$1: org.joda.money.CurrencyUnit,x$2: java.math.BigDecimal)org.joda.money.Money
[error]  cannot be applied to (org.joda.money.CurrencyUnit, scala.math.BigDecimal)
[error]     Money.of(gbp, a)
[error]           ^
```

I can use `.underlying` which works:

```
val gbp = CurrencyUnit.of("GBP")
val  a = BigDecimal("2.2")
Money.of(gbp, a.underlying)
```

But is there a better way like an implicit conversion that already exists somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like in the [scala.math.BigDecimal](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.math.BigDecimal%24), there is only

```
implicit def javaBigDecimal2bigDecimal(x: java.math.BigDecimal): BigDecimal = 
    BigDecimal(x)
```

so you would have to define it yourself:

```
implicit def scalaBigDecimal2bigDecimal(x: BigDecimal): java.math.BigDecimal = 
    x.underlying
```

I don't know if there are any libraries that already provide this conversion though.